# Нужно перегрузить операторы преобразования одного в другое. Например: человека преобразовываем в работника

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

Буду благодарен если ещё меню подскажете как сотворить:)

```
Human.h
#include "Working.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Human {

private:
    string name_h;
    string last_name_h;
    int ege_h;

public:


    Human() {}

    Human(string name_h, string last_name_h, int ege_h)
    {
        this->name_h = name_h;
        this->last_name_h = last_name_h;
        this->ege_h = ege_h;

    }

    string getname_h() { return this->name_h; }
    string getname_last_h() { return this->last_name_h; }
    int getege_h() { return this->ege_h; }

    void setname_h(string name_h) { this->name_h = name_h; }
    void setlast_name_h(string last_name_h) { this->last_name_h = last_name_h; }
    void setege_h(int ege_h) { this->ege_h = ege_h; }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Human &obj_h)
    {
        os << obj_h.name_h << endl;
        os << obj_h.last_name_h << endl;
        os << obj_h.ege_h << endl;
        return os;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream &is, Human &obj_h)
    {
        cout << "Enter name Humen" << endl;
        is >> obj_h.name_h;
        cout << "Enter Last Name Humen: " << endl;
        is >> obj_h.last_name_h;
        cout << "Enter ege Humen; " << endl;
        is >> obj_h.ege_h;
        return is;
    }







};
Student.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Human.h"
using namespace std;

class Student {

private:
    Human human;
    string name_s;
    string last_name_s;
    int ege_s;

public:

    Student() {}

    Student(string name_s, string last_name_s, int ege_s, Human human) {
        this->name_s = name_s;
        this->last_name_s = last_name_s;
        this->ege_s = ege_s;
        this->human = human;
    }

    string getname_s() { return this->name_s; }
    string getname_last_s() { return this->last_name_s; }
    int getege_s() { return this->ege_s; }

    void setname_s(string name_s) { this->name_s = name_s; }
    void setlast_name_s(string last_name_s) { this->last_name_s = last_name_s; }
    void setege_s(int ege_s) { this->ege_s = ege_s; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Student &obj_s)
    {
        os << obj_s.name_s << endl;
        os << obj_s.last_name_s << endl;
        os << obj_s.ege_s << endl;
        return os;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream &is, Student &obj_s)
    {
        cout << "Enter Name Student: " << endl;
        is >> obj_s.name_s;
        cout << "Enter Last Name Student: " << endl;
        is >> obj_s.last_name_s;
        cout << "Enter ege Student; " << endl;
        is >> obj_s.ege_s;
        return is;
    }

    /* operator Human() {

    return Human();
    } */


};
Working.h
#include <string>
#include "Human.h"

using namespace std;

class Working {

private:

    string name_w;
    string last_name_w;
    int ege_w;

public:


    Working() {}

    Working(string name_w, string last_name_w, int ege_w)
    {
        this->name_w = name_w;
        this->last_name_w = last_name_w;
        this->ege_w = ege_w;

    }

    string getname_w() { return this->name_w; }
    string getname_last_w() { return this->last_name_w; }
    int getege_w() { return this->ege_w; }

    void setname_w(string name_w) { this->name_w = name_w; }
    void setlast_name_w(string last_name_w) { this->last_name_w = last_name_w; }
    void setege_w(int ege_w) { this->ege_w = ege_w; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Working &obj_w)
    {
        os << obj_w.name_w << endl;
        os << obj_w.last_name_w << endl;
        os << obj_w.ege_w << endl;
        return os;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream &is, Working &obj_w)
    {
        cout << "Enter name Working" << endl;
        is >> obj_w.name_w;
        cout << "Enter Last Name Working: " << endl;
        is >> obj_w.last_name_w;
        cout << "Enter ege Working; " << endl;
        is >> obj_w.ege_w;
        return is;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, написать не-explicit конструктор. Если объявить `Human` другом для `Working`, можно прямо использовать закрытые поля

```
Human(const Working& w):name_h(w.name_w),...
```

если нет - соответствующие функции

```
Human(const Working& w):name_h(w.getname_w()),...
```

Можно написать оператор приведения типа в `Working` -

```
operator Human() { return Human(name_w, last_name-w, ege_w); }
```

P.S. А почему бы вам не наследовать студента и рабочего от человека? Каждый из них ведь *является* человеком, так что тут наследование вполне годится...

P.P.S. Вы пробовали это компилировать? А то у вас циклическое включение - `Human.h` включает `Working.h`, который включает `Human.h`...

P.P.P.S. Если `ege` должно означать возраст, а не оценку на ЕГЭ, то пишется это `age`, а рабочий - `Worker`..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А тут можно реализовать меню чтобы проверять работает ли преобразования?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, не связанный с первым - реализация меню. Но я бы сказал так - у вас типы без наследования, так что если компилятор пропустил - значит, преобразование выполнено :)

Answer (score 0):

Классы, которые вы пишете, слышком тривиальные, их предназначение впринципе является в хранении и выдачи трех данных, поэтому это всего лишь структуры, которым не нужны закрытые данные (вы же всеравно обеспечиваете доступ ко всем данным..).
 2. Далее, когда вы инициализируете данные в теле конструктора, то сначала создается обьект, а потом присваивается ему значение. В списке инициализатора же сразу создается обьект с данным значением
 3. И, наконец, вы постоянно повторяете один и тот же код в других классах.  С++ обеспечивает инструменты, чтобы не повторять код. Один из мощных и главных механизмов является наследование. Так как и студент и рабочий являются людьми, то их нужно создать как человек... Код станет намного короче и понятней. Дальше вы можете рабочего и студента рассматривать просто как человек....

```
struct Human {
    string name_h;
    string last_name_h;
    int ege_h;   
    Human(string name_h = "", string last_name_h = "", int ege_h = 0)
        : name_h(name_h), last_name_h(last_name_h),  ege_h(ege_h) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Human &obj_h)
    {             
        os << obj_h.name_h << endl
           << obj_h.last_name_h << endl
           << obj_h.ege_h << endl;
        return os;
    }    
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &is, Human &obj_h)
    {
       cout << "Enter name Humen" << endl;
       is >> obj_h.name_h;
       cout << "Enter Last Name Humen: " << endl;
       is >> obj_h.last_name_h;
       cout << "Enter ege Humen; " << endl;
       is >> obj_h.ege_h;
       return is;
   }
};
struct Student : Human {
    Student(string name_s = "", string last_name_s = "", int ege_h = 0)
        : Human(name_s, last_name_s, ege_h) {}
};
struct Working : Human {
    Working(string name_w = "", string last_name_w = "", int ege_h = 0)
        : Human(name_w, last_name_w, ege_h) {}
};  
int main()
 {    
     Working w("Petr", "Osipov", 44);
     Human m = w;
     cout << m;
     return 0;
 }
```